# How to Regex match on spaces and replace without overwriting spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I have a Regex match like the following code:

```
string[] specials = new string[] { "special1", "special2", "special3" };
for (int i = 0; i < specials.Length; i++)
{
    string match = string.Format("(?:\\s)({0})(?:\\s)", specials[i]);
    if (Regex.IsMatch(name, match, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        name = Regex.Replace(name, match, specials[i], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        break;
    }
}
```

What I would like is to have the replace operation replace only the matching text and leave the leading and trailing space in tact. So "This is a Special1 sentence" would become "This is a special1 sentence". With the Replace statement above I get "This is aspecial1sentence".

Solution:

Based on @Jerry's comment, I changed the match to:

`(\\s)({0})(\\s)`

and the Replace to:

`name = Regex.Replace(name, match, "$1" + specials[i] + "$3", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

and was able to get the desired results.

Comment: The simplest way would be to add them back in the replace... `Regex.Replace(name, match, " " + specials[i] + " ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);` assuming you're making `\\s` match spaces only.

Comment: @Jerry - I should have mentioned it, but that's what I'm currently doing. I have another case where the match will be `(?:^|\s)` so the space padding wouldn't always be applicable.

Comment: Okay, then the next simplest way would be to place back those spaces with capture groups. You can actually change the regex to `@"(^|\s){0}(\s|$)"` then replace with `Regex.Replace(name, match, "$1"+specials[i]+"$2", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`. `$1` will contain whatever was matched by `(^|\s)` and `$2` for the second. Though, if you want to make it even simpler, use `\b` instead of `(^|\s)` and `(\s|$)` and you won't have to place back spaces. That's assuming though that there are only alphanumeric strings in `specials`.

Comment: Could the "special" word ever occur at the start or end of the line without a trailing space?

Comment: @ClickRick - not in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookbehind and a lookahead to check for the spaces without including them in the match:

```
string[] specials = new string[] { "special1", "special2", "special3" };
for (int i = 0; i < specials.Length; i++)
{
    string match = string.Format("(?<=\\s){0}(?=\\s)", specials[i]);
    if (Regex.IsMatch(name, match, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        name = Regex.Replace(name, match, specials[i], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        break;
    }
}
```

This way you don't have to add the spaces back in.